# Como saber quais checkbox estão selecionados?

Tags: javascript

Como faço um código em javascript pra saber quais checkbox estão selecionados e ao encontrar, pegar o valor `data-id` dele?

```
<input type="checkbox" data-id="1">
<input type="checkbox" data-id="2">
<input type="checkbox" data-id="3">
```

Preciso de algo tipo assim:

```
s = '';
for (checkbox){
  if (checkbok.checked) { s+= checkbox.data-id.val(); }
}
alert(s);
```

Comment: Nenhuma [dessas perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjavascript%5d%20checkbox%20selecionado) tem o que procura?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss acho que dá pra solucionar sim, vou ver se faço a adaptação aqui. Obrigado

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo js puro ou jquery ?

Comment: @WeesSmith pode ser jquery, estou importando o arquivo .js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicionei um botão de teste para que você possa entender que a declaração de `var s` deve ser dentro do evento para que não exista resultado repetido:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-id="1">
<input type="checkbox" data-id="2">
<input type="checkbox" data-id="3">
<button id="teste">teste</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#teste").click(function(){
        var s = '';
        $.each($('input[type="checkbox"]'),function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                s+=$(this).data("id");
            }
        });
        alert(s);
    });
</script>
```

Conselho do @AndersonCarlosWoss:

```
$.each($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'),function(){
    s+=$(this).data("id");
});
```

Comment: Um detalhe: o mesmo seletor que eu utilizei funciona no jQuery. Se fizer `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')` você não precisa do *if*.

Answer (score 5):

Basta utilizar `querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')` para selecionar todos os campos marcados e utilizar o atributo `dataset` para acessar o valor de `data-id`.

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');

for (let checkbox of checkboxes) {
  console.log(checkbox.dataset.id);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-id="1" checked>
<input type="checkbox" data-id="2">
<input type="checkbox" data-id="3" checked>
```

Comment: Não sabia desse seletor @AndersonCarlosWoss, obrigado pela informação!

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = "";
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        s += $(this).attr("data-id") + ",";
    }
});
alert(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Também usando **[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** você tem como resultado uma string com os valores separados por vírgula. Exemplo:

```js
// Faz tudo de uma vez: declara a variável, cria a array,
// converte em string e atribui à variável

const s = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function(){
   return this.dataset.id;
}, []).get().join();

console.log(s); // imprime: 1,3
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-id="1" checked>
<input type="checkbox" data-id="2">
<input type="checkbox" data-id="3" checked>
```

Você pode pegar o `data-*` de duas formas:

**JavaScript puro:** `elemento.dataset.NOME`

**jQuery:** `$(seletor).data("NOME");`

Onde:

```
<input data-id> ← elemento
            ↑↑
           NOME
```